# Asp.NET menu icons rendering on each postback

Tags: asp.net, menu, master-pages

I have a master page that contains a menu bar. this menu is linked to a sitemap with dozens of options. What i have done is this to render icons to each menu item.

```
  protected void NavigationMenu_MenuItemDataBound(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
     SiteMapNode node = e.Item.DataItem as SiteMapNode;

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(node["imageUrl"]))
       e.Item.ImageUrl = node["imageUrl"];    
    }
```

I understand that on each post back, this event is going to fire. Is there a way that I can just load them once and never have to load them again ?

Comment: place it inside a custom control, and use cache on it

Comment: can you give any sample code please? i am checking it with session.. is it incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The handler is executed on every data bound event. This event usually does not get executed on every post back as once the image url is set after the ViewState is tracked it goes in the ViewState of the control.

What that means is that if DataBind() of the control(the menu) is not explicitly called this event will not be triggered.

This is at least what other data-bound controls does. For example the Grid does not re-bind itself on every post back except when paged/sort etc. -> operations that require re-build of the state.

Comment: yes but i can see the menu redrawing itself on every post back. this looks bad , and gives the feeling that the page is slow.

Comment: Of course you do. The whole page is repainted on post back. I'm not sure what your concern is here? If you are worried about slow loading time of the images you can cash them or use output cache for the menu region of the page. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c(v=vs.71).aspx